# React JS Server deployment issue

Tags: reactjs, cpanel

I have uploaded my React project on the server. also uploaded the build folder.
but data is not reflected on the server and In the root id div has nothing.

[image]

Comment: you will have to provide more details ..

Comment: It's working fine on my local. I have added the build folder and pointed the domain to the public directory.